# Accessing protected variables from parent class in JRuby

Tags: inheritance, jruby, protected

I'm trying to get at the protected variables that are defined in the parent class I have inherited from.

Is this possible? I can't find any documentation saying it is. I've seen tickets that have been closed on earlier versions of JRuby.

Any help would be great.

Edit: To clarify

```
public class Something {

  protected float somethingelse = 1.0f;

}
```

I want to get at somethingelse.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "protected variables"? Include a code example and/or the tickets you looked at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [this fix](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3018), package access, `private` and `protected` can be exposed by using `field_accessor` or `field_reader`:

```
require 'java'
java_import 'Something'


class Something
  field_accessor :somethingelse
end

class Stuff < Something
  def anotherstuff
    puts self.somethingelse
  end
end

Stuff.new.anotherstuff
```